# system can't find the file specified error while post the commands to micosoft team by using curl command

Tags: curl, cmd

I need to post the some comments to microsoft team by using curl command.I have try the follow one.

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"sent text\"}" {mywebhook}

It post sent text perfectly.but while using the below one I am facing **system can't find the file specified.**

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"**CI Status: SUCCESS :white_check_mark:Source Compilation: SUCCESS :white_check_mark:Build Location: [CI-859-Test](http://example.com/job/1) FxCop Error(s): [0](http://xxx.xml)StyleCop Error(s): [0](http://example.xml)**\"}"  {my webhookurl}

Could you please provide the suggestion to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use %20 in web url instead of space